# Windows 7 Crashes When Pasting a File

Tags: windows, windows-7, crash, copy-paste, cut-and-paste

I have a Windows 7 (Professional, x64) machine. It started crashing when pasting a file (for both copy and cut operations). The entire OS gets crashed (not just the `explorer.exe`), even on the Safe Mode.

The strange thing, the operation works when I try it on the command line.

**Crashes:**

- Copy/Cut-Paste from the Windows UI
- TeraCopy UI

  - This crashes right after opening the app. Don't know in detail how this app works. Might be doing something on initialization causing the crash.
- TeraCopy CLI

  - `TeraCopy.exe Copy C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_file.txt C:\Users\user\Desktop`

**Doesn't crash:**

- CMD

  - `copy test_file.txt test_file2.txt`
- FastCopy UI
- FastCopy CLI

  - `FastCopy.exe /cmd=force_copy C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_file.txt /to=C:\Users\user\Desktop`

**What I tried to fix the issue:**

- `chkdsk /f`
- `sfc /scannow`
- `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`

**Notes**

- The issue is only with files. I can copy/paste texts, images, or any other thing.
- The issue is only with paste operation. I can delete, download, or do anything else on files.

So I think there's an issue with my system files associated with paste operation (despite the above steps couldn't fix it). Is there a way to reinstall or repair the system files without losing data? Or any other suggestion for the issue?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-7-explorer-crashes-when-copying-files-from/0adc8fbd-51f2-4420-b8b9-e94c1b4add47)

Comment: Try a new and different User Name. Make one, log into it and test.

Comment: We cannot help you if you don’t provide any information about the BSOD. At this point a clean install is probably your only choice.

Comment: Thank you all. I created another user profile and realized that the issue does not exist with the new profile. Then, I simply copied my old user profile to a new one, as explained in the link posted by @TheCodeExpert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these 3 methods that might solve your issue:

**1.)**
Boot into safe mode and check if issue persists. If issue does not persist in safe mode then, I would suggest you place the computer in [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135) and check for the conflicting drivers or software.

**2.)**
Create a new user and check if it helps if it does help fix the [corrupted user](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Fix-a-corrupted-user-profile)

**3.)**
Uninstall MyWinLocker and the shredder program that came with it but I don't think it's ideal and I do not suggest you to do this.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-7-explorer-crashes-when-copying-files-from/0adc8fbd-51f2-4420-b8b9-e94c1b4add47)